# Why is PHP printing variables used in if statement?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am trying to print PUBLISHED date or UPDATED date if post has been updated

Here is my php if statement

```
<?php 
$u_time = the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time > $u_time) { 
echo "[UPDATED] "; the_modified_time('F j, Y'); echo " at "; the_modified_time(); echo " EST";} 
else {
echo "[PUBLISHED] "; the_time('M jS Y'); echo " at "; the_time(); echo " EST"; }
?>
```

and here is what is printed

`15479814021547981405[PUBLISHED] Jan 20th 2019 at 10:50 am EST`

but this is what am expecting

`[PUBLISHED] Jan 20th 2019 at 10:50 am EST`

Not sure why this `15479814021547981405` part is being printed out

What do i do to take that part out?

Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to give you a correct answer. What does the functions do that is undefined to us?

Comment: Clearly one of your other functions is outputting content, probably debugging code. But we don;t know and can't help you unless you show us the source code.

Comment: Can you share the code for `the_time()` and `the_modified_time()`? Seems like the unexpecting printing comes from one of them.

Comment: why the thumbs down though..i posted question based on what i know...if you need more things..ask rather than thumbing the question down..damn..if this continues this website will die in few years..too much arrogance

Comment: We have explained why we downvoted. Can you explain why you left out vital parts of the question from the people you asked help from?

Comment: This is insane - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_time/

Comment: i did not leave out vital parts..i posted what i think will help..if you need more things..you ask..not down vote

Comment: We did and you have still not included it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what worked for the logic of showing updated post date and time if post is updated and if not just show published date and time for **WORDPRESS**

```
<?php $u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
echo " [UPDATED] "; 
the_modified_time('F j, Y'); 
echo " at "; 
the_modified_time(); }
else {
echo get_the_date(); echo " at ";  echo the_modified_time(); echo " EST";
}
?>
```

So anyone looking to implement this on their **wordpress** website. go for it!!!
Solved it myself after hours of back and forth